# Increase box plot size inside Violin plot in Seaborn

Tags: seaborn

I was plotting data in a Grouped Violinplot as shown in the image.[image: Seaborn Violin Plot] Is there any way to increase the size (width) of the boxplots inside the violin plots in seaborn? As the boxplots are not even visible in the image attached.
I am also adding the code I used to generate the plots.

```
sns.set_style('whitegrid', {'font.family':'serif', 'font.serif':'Times New Roman'})


sns.set(style='white',font_scale = 7.5)
sns.color_palette("Set2")

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(60, 30))

ax.spines['left'].set_linewidth(10)
ax.spines['bottom'].set_linewidth(10)
ax.spines['left'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['bottom'].set_color('black')
ax.spines['top'].set_visible(False)
ax.spines['right'].set_visible(False)
ax.set_xlabel('')
ax = sns.violinplot(x=df.M, y=df.C, hue=df.G,scale = 'area',palette=sns.color_palette('Set2', n_colors=5),aspect=50/50,box_visible = True)
ax.set_ylabel([], fontsize = 105)
ax.set_xlabel("", fontsize = 25)
plt.legend(loc="upper left", frameon=False, fontsize=85,ncol=2)

plt.show()
```

Please help.

Thank you in advance

Comment: The elements of the plot are out of proportion because you have made the figure size enormous (60 inches by 30 inches, where  the default is something like 6 x 4). Are you doing that for a specific reason?

Comment: @mwaskom Thank you for the reply. I need to put it on a poster. However, even if it's a small image the boxplots are very thin.

Comment: Is it going to be the only thing on the poster?

Comment: @AbhinavChoudhury use sns.set_context('poster') above your regular plot to produce a plot for poster